# Cannot run or debug any test using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run or debug any test from my project " class library " , but no thing is happened .
every time I run any of the tests nothing happened.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPu6T.png)

Comment: It is really difficult to try to help you based on just a picture of your IDE.  You will have to be much more specific about what you are trying to do, what happens when you try to do it, what you have tried to do to fix it.  and provide the relevant code.  In many cases, just going through this effort you will discover the source of the problem on your own.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to write a test and run it using " class library project " using selenium by the way , but when choose any test and click on run the application I'm trying to access is not opening , so VS cannot open the URL and nothing happened on the output window , i just got ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to guess based on a picture alone but I'm guessing you're missing the run configuration in your IDE.

Comment: all i need to install is Xunit.runner.visualstudio in NuGets

Comment: Glad you figured it out!